# PHP SQL select from table where value of text

Tags: php, mysql

```
<input type="text" name="id_te" value="100"/>
```

I consider the value of text name id_te is 100.

Now I want to ask you is it possible to SELECT * from table WHERE id_te = value of text id_te ?

I use that, because I'm using jquery modal.
Jquery modal get pass id_te from a href click.

Any idea ?

Comment: it is possible, but i don't think it's save (but i don't know for sure)

Comment: I would suggest to print_r($expected_array) and see what in there.

Comment: you can use key value pair for that

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Extract the value of your field using the $_POST or $_GET and then use the following code:

```
// Connect to DB:
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'db_name');


$clean_input = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['id_te']);
$resullt = $mysqli->query("SELECT * from table WHERE id_te = '".$clean_input."'");
```

Of course, you can't really trust user input, so it might be better for you to use Prepared Statements, but the above code should give you a good starting point!

Comment: I use it in same page, how can do that ?

Comment: Set the `form` element's action to the same page, and then examine whether it has been submitted. If you don't want any page reloading, you'll need to use AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

its like you want to use the ajax:

follow or read this page to answer your question

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp